# Extracting 4 digit column names from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following column names:

```
array([u'country_name', u'country_code', u'functional_crop_code',
       u'functional_crop_type', 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967,
       1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978,
       1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989,
       1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000,
       2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011,
       2012, 2013], dtype=object)
```

I would like to extract only the column names which are 4 digits i.e. 1961, 1962... I tried this, but it does not work:

```
df.filter(regex=r'\d{4}$').columns.values
```

I get error: `*** TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have some columns that are int , hence when trying to apply the regex on those int values it fails with the error -

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

You can convert your columns to `str` and then apply the [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) -

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
df.filter(regex=r'\d{4}$').columns.values
```

Demo -

```
In [8]: df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)

In [11]: df.filter(regex=r'\d{4}$').columns.values
Out[11]:
array(['1961', '1962', '1963', '1964', '1965', '1966', '1967', '1968',
       '1969', '1970', '1971', '1972', '1973', '1974', '1975', '1976',
       '1977', '1978', '1979', '1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984',
       '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1991', '1992',
       '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000',
       '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008',
       '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013'], dtype=object)
```

---

You will need to convert to `str` before you can apply *regex* on the column name, a way (not sure if the most efficient) to not convert the column names to `str` permanently and still get the required data is -

```
df.columns[df.columns.astype(str).str.contains(r'\d{4}$')]
```

Demo -

```
In [19]: df.columns[df.columns.astype(str).str.contains(r'\d{4}$')]
Out[19]:
Index([1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972,
       1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984,
       1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996,
       1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008,
       2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: thanks @Anand, is there any way to not change the type of the column permanently? Changing the type to string messes up my code later

Comment: Added a method that uses `.str.contains`